# How to access/get the value of the component's HTML id tag on React?

Tags: html, reactjs, tags

I want to retrieve from inside a react component, the component's id to do something meaningful with it for a 3rd-part library.
How can I get it?

For instance in Ember, you can access it through `elementId`, https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Component/properties/elementId?anchor=elementId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
<div id="specialId" />
```

I think you can do:

`this.refs.specialId`